# I clicked on a virus link - What should I do?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook, malware

Using Google Chrome, my friend on Facebook tagged me on a video (probably an auto tag virus), I accidentally clicked on it (I thought that it was my friend's page). Then a new tab opened, then a popup asked me whether I wanted to launch something,

It happened so fast that I could not close that page.

*What should I do now? Is there any chance that the Facebook virus will affect Linux?*

Comment: It will affect your cookies, that means to your online account, Not the Ubuntu.

Comment: @Novice I just have cleared all my chrome data. Do you think that kind of virus can affect Chrome?

Comment: No those things works online only, it has done already what it suppose to do. Best of Luck. Hopefully it has not created any mess with your account. Intention of such things are limited to social sites only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be absolutely, positively sure *and see for yourself* that you have not been infected by a virus:

- Boot the Ubuntu LiveCD
- go to a terminal and type: `sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk`
- then in the dash, click the clamtk icon[image]
- do a full scan of `/`

*And I'll guarantee beforehand that the anti-virus will find nothing at all!*

Comment: As you're a reputation 7 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As an info, there is no virus under Linux, you can search long and won't find them, however as stated by Novice it was something more likely to mess up with your cookies.

As regard's to viruses, even though there is no virus on Linux, there is one or two Antivirus available which is usefull if you share documents between Linux and Windows systems and/or if you e-mail documents to Windows users, because even though you could keep an infected document on your Linux machine and nothing is going to happen, once it is copied/transferred/sent over to a Windows machine it will infect that machine.

Hope it helps a bit.